# Prefetch in models of complex relationships

Tags: django

Given the following models, I would like to get objects across the models in prefecth.

```
class A(models.Model)
    b = models.ForeignKey("B", related_name="a")
    code = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class B(models.Model)
    c = models.ForeignKey("C", related_name="b", blank=True, null=True)

class C(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)


c_list = C.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        "b__a",
        queryset=A.objects.order_by("code"),
        to_attr="a_list",
    )
)

for c in c_list:
    print(c.a_list)
```

The following error occurs

```
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'a_list'
```

I want to get an object of A directly from an object of C. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your modeling schema is wrong, you will never get an A object from C

Comment: prefetch does not "fold", it is, imho, one of the bad things about it: it sets an `a_list` on every `B` object, so `for c in c_list: for b in c.b(): for a in c.a_list.all()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a_list` has been added to the B instances

```
for c in c_list:
    for b in c.b.all():
        print(b.a_list)
```

To my knowledge, prefetches cannot do give you a list of A instances in a C instance without a FK between the two